# getting the all the href links of the page using ruby capybara

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm having an issue getting the list of links of the pages and saving it as an array, so I can find out what links are used in the page

```
<ul class="test">   
 <li class="social_1"></li>
     <a href="link1"></a>   
 <li class="social_2"></li>
     <a href="link2"></a>   
 <li class="social_3"></li>
     <a href="link3"></a>   
 <li class="social_4"></li>
     <a href="link4"></a> 
</ul>
```

I tried using

```
list_items = page.all('li').collect(&:href)
puts list_items;
```

but it's not giving the correct answer.

im having this error

```
  undefined method `href' for #<Capybara::Element tag="li"> (NoMethodError)
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `list_items = page.all('a').collect(&:href)`?

Comment: Is there a typo in the HTML of the li elements - ie is the link element supposed to be a sibling of the li element? I would assume it is meant to be a child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two issues:

- The href attribute exist on the a element rather than the li element.
- Elements do not have an href method. To get the attribute value use the `[]` method.

Depending on your preference, any of the following would work:

```
page.all('li').map { |li| li.find('a')['href'] }

page.all('li a').map { |a| a['href'] }

page.all('a').map { |a| a['href'] }
```